# How many cube roots does an $n\times n$ identity matrix have over $\mathbb C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I thought there are infinite solutions, because if $A$ is a solution, then $Q^TAQ$  is also a solution, where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix. But I used MATLAB to symbolically solve for the cube root of a $2\times 2$ identity matrix, I got 16 solutions. Every entry of the solutions is either $0$ or a cube root of $1$.
MATLAB is unable to solve for higher $n$. So how many cube roots does an $n\times n$ identity matrix have? $n^4$?

Comment: Are the matrices allowed to have complex entries?

Comment: Why is $Q^T A Q$ also a solution?

Comment: @quid $(Q^TAQ)^3=Q^TA^3Q=Q^TIQ=I$

Comment: @TrevorNorton thanks, that was a bit dump of me. I did not register that we are talking about root of the *identity* matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The identity matrix indeed has infinitely many real $k$th roots, for any $k$, whenever $n \geq 3$.

For one, we can note that the block matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{\pmatrix{\cos(2 \pi/k) & \sin (2\pi/k)\\-\sin (2\pi/k) & \cos (2 \pi/k)} & \pmatrix{t I_{n-2}\\0}\\
0 & I_{n-2}}
$$
will always satisfy $A^k = I_n$, for any $t \in \Bbb R$.

In fact, the same is also true when $n = 2$.  We can take
$$
\pmatrix{\cos(2 \pi/k) & t\sin (2\pi/k)\\-\frac 1t\sin (2\pi/k) & \cos (2 \pi/k)}
$$
for any non-zero $t \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks! glad to know that MATLAB is wrong..

Comment: The OP's original argument (similarity transformations) can be used to produce infinitely many cube roots (or k'th roots) of the identity matrix even in the $2\times 2$ case.

Comment: So if $A$ is a solution, then $PAQ$ is a solution, as long as $PQ = QP = I$. Here $P=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1/t
  \end{bmatrix}$ and $Q=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & t
  \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @hardmath yes, but then I wouldn't be able to start with the rotation matrix, since there are *not* infinitely many orthogonal $k$th roots of identity.

Comment: @ZiqianXie exactly!  In fact, a similar argument works for the $n \geq 3$ case as well.